# Como obter o sentido do dispositivo utilizando giroscópio e acelerometro? Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic, javascript-eventos, compass, orientation

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em Ionic 3, em que necessito saber para qual sentido o celular do usuário está apontando, e então fazer a tomada de decisão. Eu estava tentando utilizar o plugin Device Orientation, que retorna um valor em graus (0 - 360) em que 0º é Norte, só que muitos celulares (inclusive o meu) não possuem sensor magnético. Eu estava lendo que se eu combinar os dados do giroscópio e acelerômetro, seria possível encontrar o tal eixo Azimuth que refere aos valores em graus. Só que está sendo tanta informação (como ângulos Euler, velocidade angular, fórmulas matemáticas, etc) que eu não sei nem por onde começar.

A unica solução paliativa que encontrei foi utilizar o `DeviceOrientationEvent` do JavaScript, que me entrega o angulo de 0-360, mas eu não sei de onde ele tira esse valor e nem sei se o 0º realmente é o norte.

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (event) => {
  this.alpha= event.alpha;
  this.beta = event.beta;
  this.gamma = event.gamma;})
```

Enfim, se alguem souber de alguma outra solução em que poderei saber para onde o sentido do usuário também é valido.